# How to convert a date in a given format

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date in this format:

20110122000000.000

how can I change that so it's

```
12.01.2011
```

(12 January 2011)

Then I use this in php:

```
$origDate = "20110112000000.000";
$newDate = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($origDate));
```

it can output something like:

```
01.12.2011
```

Thanks!

Comment: If your PHP code works, just change d.m.Y to m.d.Y?

Comment: @Dan, I made that assumption at first, the code doesn't produce expected results.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using >= PHP 5.3

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20110112000000.000');
echo $date->format('d.m.Y');
```

I can't test PHP 5.3 here, so if that extraneous stuff is playing up `createFromFormat()`, just remove it first.

I don't know about *all* your formats, but this will remove all `0` and `.` at the end of your string.

```
$date = rtrim($date, '.0')
```

And because the most significant number is always on the right, (`2` in this example), it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$origDate = "20110112000000.000";
# strip stuff after the period because strptime doesn't support milliseconds
$date = preg_replace("/\.\d+$/", "", $origDate);
$time = strptime($date, "Ymdhms");
$newDate = strftime("%m.%d.%Y", mktime($time));
echo $newDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing at your date format that the numbers are consistently placed you can manually form the timestamp:

```
$origDate = "20110112000000.000";
$newDate = date("d.m.Y", mktime(0,0,0,
    substr($origDate, 4, 2), // month
    substr($origDate, 6, 2), // day
    substr($origDate, 0, 4)) // year
);
```

Which produces `01.12.2011`